# Cannot run the npm install command in the react due to proxy restriction

Tags: npm, proxy

I am currently working under a network that is secured by a proxy server. So I I am not able to run npm install command and install the packgages from npm. Is there way to configure the proxy in the package.json and how can it be done?

Comment: what is the throwed error?

Comment: npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/intl/-/intl-1.2.5.tgz failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.11.11.1:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: `` npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anushka-SP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-13T07_24_12_839Z-debug.log ``

Answer (score 0):

You can set proxy in npm directly and all install commands will go via this proxy.

npm set registry http://xyz:1234

Comment: npm set registry [ what should be here ]

Comment: is it the proxy address

Comment: This is command to set proxy in npm. Proxy address you need to figure it out, in my case my organization provide proxy for npm.